# Slow write to LVM with snapshot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, lvm

I use Ubuntu 10.04 Server. Write very slow, when I use LVM snaphot. This is normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is normal?

Yes([Link1](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/02/05/disaster-lvm-performance-in-snapshot-mode/), [Link2](http://www.nikhef.nl/~dennisvd/lvmcrap.html)).
On my server(4x SATA RAID):

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/test/foo count=10 bs=1024k
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.103387 s, 97.3 MB/s

# dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/test2/bar count=10 bs=1024k
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.722223 s, 13.8 MB/s
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this, too.
Using only SATA drives with diffrent combinations: with/without RAID 1/5/10 sw and hw.
This is caused by high I/O usage by snapshot volume.
I'm going to save snapshots on separate volumes... or use SAS/SCSI.
usual SATA drive - around 300 tps
usual SCSI drive - can do around 1000 tps and more
Check by iostat what is going on in Your system.